# How to get an id of a field or textbox in spd

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm working on a NewForm.aspx in SPD.I want to get an id of field or textbox how to get that.because they are using ID such as "ff6{$Pos}"

Answer (score 0):

The ID is not allocated by SharePoint until the form is saved to the list - so it will not be available in NewForm.

Comment: Thank u.Then suppose Based one value i want hide one textbox ,how i ll do

Comment: and one more thing like which button and which control i sud use in SPD like html or asp or sharepoint

Comment: I have done this in the past using jQuery.  If you want to apply it to all forms then add it to your master page but if it is just the one form then add the script directly to that form.

Comment: Then better is,I can get ID at run time with help of F12